# Target in HTML how to open in Adobe Flash Player

Tags: html, flash, adobe, milestone

Here I was creating an HTML menupage for a presentation that uses flash animations. I am using this code:

```
<a href="url" target="_blank></a>
```

Now as you seem the target="_blank" opens a new Internet explorer window. What I want to do is to open my presentations into a SWF window. Is that possible?

Comment: Doesn't work. It opens in the same window. I want it to open in Adobe Flash Player

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to open in Adobe Flash
>   Player

This can't be done without support of target SWF. One possibility is:

- make all such link point to same SWF that will open them: href="player.swf"
- add parameters to url for SWF to determine what content to show: href="player.swf?pageId=123"
- in SWF, get parameters and load that content.